# how to do a htaccess 301 redirect with query strings?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, query-string, http-status-code-301

i have some links that i need to redirect, like:

```
/pass-help.php?action=1&email=test@test.com to /about/help
or
/contests/contest-a?testa=1&testb=1 /user/index/contest
```

i need a way to find the `action` or the `email` in the links above because they can be anything.

maybe something like /pass-help.php?action=`(\?.+)`&email=`(\?.+)` to /about/help

but im not sure how to write the query string.

any ideas?

if so, please explain a bit so i can understand what is happening.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the query strings don't matter, you can just ignore them:

via mod_alias:

```
Redirect 301 /pass-help.php /about/help?
Redirect 301 /contests/contest-a /user/index/contest?
```

via mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^/?pass-help\.php$ /about/help? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?contests/contest-a /user/index/contest? [L,R=301]
```

Note that in the mod_alias case, there will be a stary `?` at the end. That's needed in order to get rid of the query string.

If the query strings need to have some param names, but you don't care about the values:

via mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)action=
RewriteCond %{QUERY)STRING{ (^|&)email=
RewriteRule ^/?pass-help\.php$ /about/help? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)testa=
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)testb=
RewriteRule ^/?contests/contest-a /user/index/contest? [L,R=301]
```

If the query strings need to have some param names with EXACTLY some value:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)action=1
RewriteCond %{QUERY)STRING{ (^|&)email=test@test.com
RewriteRule ^/?pass-help\.php$ /about/help? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)testa=1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)testb=1
RewriteRule ^/?contests/contest-a /user/index/contest? [L,R=301]
```